# For loop breaks for no apparente reason

Tags: python

If I run the following code, I get i = 42598.

```py
import numpy as np
all_sets = []
working_sets = []

numbers = np.arange(10)
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

i = 0
expression = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
for n1 in numbers:
    expression[0] = str(n1)
    for o1 in operators:
        expression[1] = o1
        for n2 in numbers:
            expression[2] = str(n2)
            for o2 in operators:
                expression[3] = o2
                for n3 in numbers:
                    expression[4] = str(n3)
                    for o3 in operators:
                        expression[5] = o3
                        for n4 in numbers:
                            expression[6] = str(n4)
                            i += 1

                            # get all sets for comparison
                            numbers = sorted([expression[0], expression[2], expression[4], expression[6]])
                            if not (numbers in all_sets):
                                all_sets.append(numbers)

print(i)
```

But if I comment out the this bit

```
# get all sets for comparison
numbers = sorted([expression[0], expression[2], expression[4], expression[6]])
if not (numbers in all_sets):
    all_sets.append(numbers)
```

I get i = 640000. WHY? What is breaking my for loop?

Comment: You have a `for n4 in numbers` loop, and then inside that loop, you're changing the contents of `numbers`.  Of course that is going to have an effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numbers` array starts out with 10 elements but at some point execution is going to reach the place where you change it to only contain 4 values (`numbers = sorted([expression[0], expression[2], expression[4], expression[6]])`).  All the loops on numbers that were initially going to run 10 times will be cut short to 4 from then on.  This may give the impression that a break occurred but actually the loops just reached the (new) end of the array.